# jQuery increasing particular number within particular time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a question. Any idea how to increase particular number to bigger number within particular time?(Using jQuery) For example, I want to make percent bar and when bar sliding to particular size at the same time increasing number from 0 to 100. I creat bar but haven't idea how to realize number transformation within particular time. Visually, it looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick fiddle to show you an example on how to get the percent based on the filled amount: http://jsfiddle.net/jYveX/

Basically I find out the width of the parent wrapper (400), then the width of the fill (200) and do a simple calculation using jquery. 400/200 = 50.

Now when you increase the size of your fill bar, the percent should change along with the width of the bar.

HTML

```
<div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar-fill">
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar-container {
    width:400px;
    height:40px;
    background:green;
}
.bar-fill {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    text-align:right;
}
```

JS

```
$('.output').html($('.bar-fill').width() / 4 + '%');
```

Here's an example of the animation in progress:

The key was to use the step option that is available in the [animate class](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).

http://jsfiddle.net/jYveX/4/

Comment: Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jYveX/1/ How to make when red line sliding, percent increasing from 0 to 75 at the same time? (start:0,1,2,3...74,75end)

Comment: You can use the step option in animate, here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/jYveX/4/

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as resolved just incase somebody else has the same question, cheers :)